# How to use extended character set in reading ini file? (C++ lang.)

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, character, ini

I face one little problem. I am from country that uses extended character set in language (specifically Latin Extended-A due to characters like š,č,ť,ý,á,...).

I have ini file containing these characters and I would like to read them into program. Unfortunatelly, it is not working with getPrivateProfileStringW or ...A.

Here is part of source code. I hope it will help someone to find solution, because I am getting a little desperate. :-)

SOURCE CODE:

```
wchar_t pcMyExtendedString[200];    

GetPrivateProfileStringA(
             "CATEGORY_NAME",
             "SECTION_NAME",
             "error",
             pcMyExtendedString,
             200,
             PATH_TO_INI_FILE
             );
```

INI FILE:

```
 [CATEGORY_NAME]
 SECTION_NAME= ľščťžýáíé
```

Characters ý,á,í,é are readed correctly - they are from character set *Latin-1 Supplement*. Their hexa values are correct (0xFD, 0xE1, 0xED,...).

Characters ľ,š,č,ť,ž are readed incorrectly - they are from character set *Latin Extended-A* Their hexa values are incorrect (0xBE, 0x9A, 0xE8,...). Expected are values like 0x013E, 0x0161, 0x010D, ...

How could be this done? Is it possible or should I avoid these characters at all?

Comment: Yes, it is true. This is only example code and I wanted to keep it as most easiest as it could be - so no retyping of parameters, no structs, ...
I wanted only to show main purpose of code. :-)

Comment: Have you tried reading in the file with [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.ini_parser)?

Comment: Still using the olden .ini configuration file format is a pretty drastic mistake.  It dates from an era before Unicode, the api is completely agnostic of it.  The .ini file is read assuming the default system code page, that only works reliably if the file was created on the same machine on which your code runs.  The file doesn't have to travel far if you live in Slovakia to produce gibberish.

Comment: Using unicode .ini file and `GetPrivateProfileStringW` works and read the correct values for me.

Comment: [This project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9071/Using-Unicode-in-INI-files) may be worth a look.

Comment: Use utf8-encoded INI file and do not use GetProfile**string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetPrivateProfileString` doesn't do any character conversion. If the call succeed, it will gives you exactly what is in the file.

Since you want to have unicode characters, your file is probably in UTF-8 or UTF-16. If your file is UTF-8, you should be able to read it with `GetPrivateProfileStringA`, but it will give you a `char` array that will contain the correct UTF-8 characters (that is, not 0x013E, because 0x013E is not UTF-8).

If your file is UTF-16, then `GetPrivateProfileStringW` should work, and give you the UTF-16 codes (0x013E, 0x0161, 0x010D, ...) in a `wchar_t` array.

Edit: Actually your file is encoded in [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250). This is a single byte encoding, so `GetPrivateProfileStringA` works fine, and you can convert it to UTF-16 if you want by using `MultiByteToWideChar` with 1250 as code page parameter.

Comment: The file is clearly NOT in UTF-8, based on the OP's example. But if `GetPrivateProfileStringA()` returns the raw bytes as-is, then you can read and convert them manually to UTF-16 using `MultiByteToWideChar()`.

Comment: This solution worked! 
Final process to read local characters consists these steps:

1. Save (ANSI) ini file with special characters - ľ,š,ď,...
2. Create extended char string - wchar_t pcTemp[200];
3. Create basic char string - char pcMyExtendedString[200];
4. Load my chars into basic string - GetPrivateProfileStringA();
5. Transformate basic string to extended char string - MultiByteToWideChar(1250, 0, pcMyExtendedString, sizeof(pcMyExtendedString), pcTemp, sizeof(pcMyExtendedString));
Done.

I hope this will help someone. Thanks ElderBug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the file in UTF-8 - CodePage 65001 encoding, most likely your file would be in Western European (Windows) - CodePage 1252.